# Replace string with numeric values based on dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
strings = ["acbd", "abc", "acbde", "abc"]
```

And a dictionary containing numeric representations of each character:

```
dict_ = {"a":[0.4, 0.3, 0.8, -0.1], "b":[1.5, -1.6, 1.2], "c":[7.4, 4.3], "d":[4.23, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 1.7], "e":[1.5, 8.1]}
```

How can I get a numeric representation for each string in `strings`? For example, for "acbd", I want a concatenated list of the constituent characters in order: `[0.4, 0.3, 0.8, -0.1, 7.4, 4.3, 1.5, -1.6, 1.2, 4.23, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 1.7]`. I want an output with a list of lists, with each list being a numeric representation of the string.

What is the most efficient way of doing this also?

My real data has over 100000 strings and all 26 characters.

Comment: a straightforward approach like `[[x for c in s for x in dict_[c]] for s in strings]` should be reasonably performant for a problem of this size... have you tried this?

Comment: I'm personally a fan of (the now somewhat depreciated) `reduce` function: `[functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, [dict_[c] for c in string]) for string in strings]` Not significantly different than @juanpa.arrivillaga 's solution, but more readable to me..

Comment: @Aaron it is *significantly less performant* in general. `x + y` is a linear operation with sequences (i.e. `list` objects). Thus, you will have polynomial time overall. But might not be an issue in the inner loop if the size of the strings isn't too big.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually my testing so far shows my version being anywhere from 50% as fast to about 90% as fast as your version no matter how much input I throw at it (number of strings, length of strings, length of number lists). It's true yours is a bit faster, but it would seem that the time complexity of the two is fairly close to the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In general the problem as described does not encompass that much data (a couple 10's to 100's of MB maybe?), so small differences in performance should matter less than readability in which case both our answers are not as good as a proper `for` loop written out over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using `itertools.chain` and a list comprehension.

This has no optimisation for repeated strings. I suggest you test with your data to see if performance is adequate.

```
from itertools import chain

res = [list(chain.from_iterable(map(dict_.get, i))) for i in strings]

print(res)

[[0.4, 0.3, 0.8, -0.1, 7.4, 4.3, 1.5, -1.6, 1.2, 4.23, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 1.7],
 [0.4, 0.3, 0.8, -0.1, 1.5, -1.6, 1.2, 7.4, 4.3],
 [0.4, 0.3, 0.8, -0.1, 7.4, 4.3, 1.5, -1.6, 1.2, 4.23, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 1.7, 1.5, 8.1],
 [0.4, 0.3, 0.8, -0.1, 1.5, -1.6, 1.2, 7.4, 4.3]]
```

Comment: ... the OP asked for a list-of-lists. Anyway, this would blow out any non-unique strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Sure, I updated to list-of-list. Sorry, I don't understand the point about blowing out non-unique strings.

Comment: So, consider what happens to the string for `abc` in this sample data... it appears twice in the list, but you would only keep the last one with a dict. this may or may not be an issue, of course...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Yeh I see what you mean, good point. As you say, it's not clear *how much* it's an issue. OP should test with their data.